# "h" in Sindhi - ھ vs ہ

Tags: indo-aryan, indian-languages, urdu, perso-arabic-script

In Urdu, `ہ` is called *gol he* and `ھ` is called *docašmī he*.
However in Sindhi, there seems to be only one for both (*choṭī he*), which is [officially](http://learn.sindhila.edu.pk/index.php/alphabets/basic-alphabets) `ھ`.
(Please let me know if I'm wrong here) (Ref: [Sindhi Alphabets](https://omniglot.com/writing/sindhi.htm))

But in [Sindhi Wikipedia](https://sd.wikipedia.org/), I see heavy usage of `ہ` (especially Arabic `ه`).

Why so? Is it because colloquially written Sindhi is heavily influenced by Urdu alphabet?

For example, I see `آھي` and `آهي` being used interchangeably.

How do we deal with this (or clean this) for computational purposes?

---

Edit: (Another confusing example)
In the sentence [پڙهڻ ۾ ڏکيائي](https://sd.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%88%DA%AA%D9%8A%D9%BE%D9%8A%DA%8A%D9%8A%D8%A7:%D9%BE%DA%99%D9%87%DA%BB_%DB%BE_%DA%8F%DA%A9%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%8A), the Sindhi word `پڙهڻ` translates to Urdu as `پڑھائی`. Notice that `ڑھ` in Urdu uses `ھ` but `ڙه` in Sindhi uses `ہ`. Why these confusions?

Comment: One reason for the heavy use of heh U+0647 may be the keyboard layouts being used. On the Apple Sindhi layout, this is the top level h character. You can get U+06be heh doachashmee only on the Shift level, but Apple's default Arabic script fonts don't seem to have the right middle and final forms. I don't know about the Windows keyboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you say different? My browser renders those "different" examples identically:
[image]

They are *definitely* encoded differently, because a search for `ه` will only highlight one of the two:

[image]

So what's going on?

Arabic and related scripts type characters *differently* depending on their position in a word. Let's just consider the plain ﻩ (h) for a moment:

| Lone | Final | Medial | Initial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ﻩ | ﻪ | ﻬ | ﻫ |

So far so good. This is, for all intents and purposes, the "Arabic ه" as you phrased it, since it's the only one you will run into [when reading Arabic](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D8%BA%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%A9), and the most common form of h ه you will encounter elsewhere.

One big exception to this are the Arabizations of the Eastern Indo-Aryan languages which split ه into two: the "freeform" *choṭī he* and the "two-eyed" *docašmī he*.

The tricky part is that not all languages (neither all fonts) spell their *choṭī* and *docašmī* he's identically.

| Lone | Final | Medial | Initial | Letter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ہ | ‎ ـہ‎ | ـہـ‎ | ہـ | Naskh choṭī he |
| ھ‎ | ـھ‎ | ـھـ‎ | ھـ | Naskh docašmī he |
| ہ | ‎ ـہ | ـھـ‎ | ھـ | Sindhi docašmī he |

Sindhi does not actually have a *choṭī he*, unlike Urdu. So Sindhi employs additional letters for aspirated consonants (with the exceptions of جهي and گهي). The Sindhi *docašmī he*, which is closer to the Arabic ﻩ, fulfills the role of *choṭī he* in Urdu. It is used for the `h` sound and vowels, in Sindhi.

But if you look closely in the final and lone positions it visually resembles the Naskh *choṭī he*. So, to type these on a computer, Sindhi speakers can substitute the Naskhi *choṭī he*. This is why [Sindhi Wikipedia](https://sd.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D9%8F%DA%A9_%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%88) shows a lot more ﻩ's than ـہ's, h just occurs in non-final positions more frequently.

In conclusion, in Sindhi ھ and ہ are the same letter, but are represented by different codes because those codes were originally designed to accommodate Arabic and Urdu typography. This is just how Sindhi speakers have adapted.

Comment: Yes, setting up that table WAS a nightmare

Comment: ADDENDUM: The choice of whether to use ـہ or ﻪ differs from website to website. The only website which I have seen to consistently prefer ـہ  over ﻪ was http://dic.sindhila.edu.pk/ .

Comment: Thank you... makes sense :) So in conclusion, it is expected in Sindhi to consistently use either the unicode character of `ھ` or `ہ`, but in places like Wikipedia where everyone contributes, we see mixture of do chashmi he, gol he and Arabic's choti he. So for computationally purposes (like Natural Language Processing), it would make sense to normalize the 3 unicode variants to a single standard one. Am I right?

Comment: I guess, but only the under assumption that the entire page is in Sindhi.

Comment: Ofcourse. It would have been great if they had included both `ھ` and `ہ` characters while standardizing Sindhi. Without this, it would be difficult to differentiate computationally between digraphs (consonant+`ھ`, where `ھ` is an aspiration) and normal Arabic usage (consonant+`ہ`, where `ہ` denotes *he*)

Comment: Do you know what the standard is for printed Sindhi these days? Is any effort made to distinguish the "h" used to indicate aspiration of certain consonants from the independent "h" character?    The one old book I have seems to use the same ـھـ‎ form for both.  Which final form is preferred?  My book uses ـہ .  None of my fonts have that final form for U+06be

Comment: To my knowledge the ـہ form is especially popular in cursive/handwriting. (Not just for Sindhi). The digital world is a mixed bag so far as I can tell.

Comment: In searching around the last couple days I have been surprised to find  the ـہ form in several online newspapers also in https://sl.sindhila.org/en/publications/sla-newsletter.  Perhaps there is a special font that does this.